# What cipher is the "best" or better for LUKS?

Tags: disk-encryption

I am looking for strong cipher for LUKS, currently I am thinking about SHA512, but encryption is not my cup of tea, so could you give me your hints, what are you using for encryption?

Comment: SHA512 is rather too one-wayish for a crypto cipher...

Comment: What is your use case?  What kind of data are you trying to protect, what are you trying to protect against, and are there any applicable legal/regulatory compliances involved?

Comment: I am trying to protect myself basically against police or court order, here is no any restriction or regulation.

Comment: Ency, I don't know what country you are in, but in the US (and several others), a Court can order you to turn over your encryption keys and or passwords, and basically keep you in jail until you do. Just an FYI.

Comment: Do you care more about throughput or privacy? Also what CPU do you have? Some CPUs from Intel have instructions for AES encryption.

Comment: Ask on http://security.stackexchange.com/ perhaps?  The cipher has almost nothing to do with a court order though.  A court could order you to give up you keys even if you where using ROT13.

Comment: We do not have restriction about that. Well I dont have CPU with this feature.

Comment: @zoredache: Since he is most likely trying to commit crimes (i.e. obstruct legal investigations and court orders) we probably shouldn't help him there either.

Comment: @packs: You and everyone else has a right on privacy (or are you from china or kldr?) and that's what i want to have, no one is able to see may data without may permission.

Comment: @ency: That's more of a side conversation, and a good one. Legally, the only privacy you have is what the law gives you. Legally/constitutionally/whatever issued court orders and/or searches/seizures will trump those protections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go with the default unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: I know what I am doing, I am just not so good in cryptography, that is why i am asking ...

Comment: I believe the default for LUKS is AES-CBC with a 256 bit key size. This is a pretty good all around choice. As mentioned unless you know more about cryptography than the developers of LUKS, staying with the default is probably a good choice.

Comment: Cryptography is hard, really hard. The key strength, algorithm, use case, and cipher mode need to all fit together like a puzzle, or else the whole is weaker than the sum.  Unless you have a strong understanding of all those parts, then the defaults are usually better.  That being said, AES-CBC with a 256 bit key sounds reasonable from my understanding of them.